# SQL Stored procedure delete duplicate records, keep one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, duplicates, syntax-error

I'm using 3 tables `tblproduct`, `tblstock` and `tblwinkel`.

There is are foreign keys `productid` and `winkelid` in the `tblstock` table.

The `tblstock` table has a field `stock` as well, which is an integer.

I only want to have 1 record with the same combination of the 2 foreign keys `winkelid` and `productid`. The stock value of this record contains the sum of all the other records with the same foreign keys combination of `winkelid` and `productid`.

So, I'm trying to delete all the other records with the same 2 foreign keys in it, so I just keep 1.

My stored procedure keeps giving the following error:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure uspRecordsSamenvoegen, Line 11
>   'int' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

Little help please ?

This is my stored procedure so far:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspRecordsSamenvoegen 

@winkelid int, @productid int
AS
BEGIN
declare stocktotaal int

    SET NOCOUNT ON

select sum(Stock) into stocktotaal from TblStock where WinkelId = @winkelid and ProductId = @productid;
delete from TblStock where WinkelId = @winkelid and ProductId = @productid;
insert into TblStock values(@winkelid, @productid, stocktotaal);

END
GO
```

Comment: are winkelid and productid passed in to uspRecordsSamenvoegen?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare stocktotaal int
```

needs to be

```
declare @stocktotaal int
```

Without the '@' to declare a variable, the sql parser is looking to setup a cursor. Also, you can't select into a variable. Your select should look like the following:

```
select @stocktotaal = sum(stock) from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

so your results would be captured by:

```
select WinkelId, ProductId, sum(Stock) as stocktotaal 
from TblStock
group by WinkelId, ProductId
```